# numpy group by, returning original indexes sorted by the result

Tags: python, numpy, group-by

i have array like this :

```
array([[2, 1],
       [3, 5],
       [2, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [5, 3]])
```

What i want to do is 'group-by' sum by first column and then sort by second column :

```
array([[2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [5, 3],
       [4, 2]])
```

and here comes the twist, I want to also get back the indexes from the original array of every row
in the result array, sorted :

```
     2       3     5    4
 [[0,2,4],  [1],  [5], [3] ]
```

OR if its easy .. i need to get the top N indexes ... let say top 2 :

```
     2       3    
  [0,2,4,    1]
```

No pandas, only pure numpy.

BTW, i need only the top N items and their indexes .. this may simplify speedup the process

---

trying to apply any of this:

https://izziswift.com/is-there-any-numpy-group-by-function

Comment: prefer w/o loops ... but if not possible, then good

Comment: `np.unique` applied to the 1st column may be a start.  `unique` sorts its array, and then looks for adjacent duplicates.  `pandas` has a convenient `group_by` (not necessarily fast), but `numpy` does not.

Comment: its for my own project ... this is the last step of overlap-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is sadly no group-by in Numpy, but you can use `np.unique` to find the unique elements and their index which is enough to implement what you need. One the keys as been identified, you can perform a key-based reduction using `np.add.at`. For the sort by value, you can use `np.argsort`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004364) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698687) for more information.

```py
keys, index = np.unique(df[:,0], return_inverse=True) # Find the unique key to group
values = np.zeros(len(keys), dtype=np.int64)          # Sum-based accumulator
np.add.at(values, index, df[:,1])                     # Key-based accumulation
tmp = np.hstack([keys[:,None], values[:,None]])       # Build the key-sum 2D array
res = tmp[tmp[:, 1].argsort()[::-1]]                  # Sort by value
```

Note that the index can be easily obtained from the `index` variable (which is a reversed index). There is no way to build it with Numpy but this is possible using a simple python loop accumulating the index `i` in lists stored in a dictionary for in each key `keys[index[i]]`. Here is an example:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(df)): d[keys[index[i]]].append(i)
```

Comment: yeah most of the solutions seem to require building a index ...   add.at? hmm

Answer (score 1):

I'm not happy with this solution and can't verify that it will not break with other data. It's using the referenced idea to group, but sums with `add.reduceat`.

```
a = np.array(
      [[2, 1],
       [3, 5],
       [2, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [5, 3]])

s = a[:,0].argsort()
b = a[s]
groups, index = np.unique(b[:,0], return_index=True)
# splits = np.split(b[:,1], index[1:]) # if you need the groups
groupsum = np.stack([groups, np.add.reduceat(b[:,1], index)]).T
groupsum[(groupsum[:,1]*(-1)).argsort()]
```

Output

```
array([[2, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [5, 3],
       [4, 2]])
```

To get the indices for each group

```
np.stack([groups.astype(object),np.split(np.arange(len(a))[s], index[1:])]).T
```

Output

```
array([[2, array([0, 2, 4])],
       [3, array([1])],
       [4, array([3])],
       [5, array([5])]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find useful a simple general purpose `group_by` function that I posted for this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150915/3671939

You can use it to solve this problem as follows:

```py
x = np.array([[2, 1], [3, 5], [2, 1], [4, 2], [2, 3], [5, 3]])
keys, idxs, sums = group_by(x[:, 0], lambda idx: [x[idx[0], 0], idx, x[idx, 1].sum()]).T

N = 2
top = np.argsort(-sums)[:N]
print(keys[top])  # [2 3]
print([idxs[i] for i in top])  # [array[0, 2, 4], array[1]]
```

Note that the function is fast, but does not exploit that "only the N-top" are requested. This could be done by using `np.argpartition` and then sort for the smaller array, although it may not produce any significant benefit as the group_by part has O(n log n) complexity plus many constants:

```py
top = np.argpartition(sums, -N)[-N:]
top = top[np.argsort(-sums[top])]
```